# JQuery - How to concatenate text with .each?

Tags: jquery, concatenation

First of all, excuse me for my bad english.

I've tried various methods but haven't had any luck as of yet.

I'm returning a series of objects with .each()method.

I'd like to populate  the "value" attribute of a input field with each value from the object.
I didnt find a way to do the same thing as PHP .=

Any idea would be great!

Here's my code :

```
$.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function(){
        var data = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(1)"); 
         $("#login").val(data.text());
    })
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var c = '';
$.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function(){
    var data = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(1)"); 
    c += data.text();
})
$("#login").val(c);
```

You could also have used this in the loop :

```
$("#login").val($("#login").val(c)+data.text());
```

but I personally prefer to minimize the changes of the DOM.

Note also that using traversals like `parent().parent()` lead to maintenance problems. In your case you could probably use

```
var data = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1)");
```

so that the code won't break if a `span` or any other elements wraps your input in the future.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/). You can pass the `delimiter` character to [join()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to separate the alues.

```
text = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").map( function(){
    return $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(1)");        
}).get().join();

$("#login").val(text);
```

Comment: This is a lot more elegant and should be the accepted answer.